# How do I install wireless adapter for ubuntu 21.04 on Macbook pro 2019

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro, adapter, 21.04

I'm new to these forums and am a super noob to linux/ubuntu (I'm not sure how to do most things yet) and I'm having trouble finding help for this problem I'm having.

In the settings it's showing "No Wireless adapter found". I'm dual booting from my Macbook pro 2019 13.3 in with touch bar.

I've searched for previous solutions to this problem but none seem to work in my case. I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and rebooted but it didn't work. (I'm currently on ethernet direct connection but would like to move to wireless)

When running `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` I get:

`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4377b Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4488] (rev 04)`

How exactly do I go about installing the proper drivers for my wireless network adapter?

I'd be happy to provide more information or run any commands if need be.

Comment: Simplest solution is to buy a USB wifi adapter and use that. Nobody has yet reverse engineered a driver for the 2019 MacBook Pro. I’m sure the sites you followed that walked you through the kernel updates, the disabling of the T2 chip, and the audio drivers said as much as well 

Comment: Yeah, I was actually thinking this as being a workaround solution. I'll have to pick one up thanks.

Comment: Can you try this: in Activities, search for and go to Additional Drivers, activate Broadcom wireless driver.

Comment: And run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`t` and run the terminal commands:

```
sudo dmesg | grep brcm
sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio
```

When you find nothing that relates to your wireless device or, more likely, nothing at all, you will see that there is currently no working driver that covers your device.

A Google search finds a few sites that suggest that the correct driver is *brcmfmac*; however, the driver doesn't claim the device. Confirm with:

```
modinfo brcmfmac | grep 4488
```

As was mentioned in the comments, we suggest a USB wireless device until a Linux driver is released. This site may be helpful in finding one that is supported without having to locate, compile and install an out-of-kernel driver: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397914

Comment: I have now Ubuntu 21.04 running on Macbook Pro 5,5 (year 2009) or 8,1 (year 2011) with wifi working with Broadcom wireless driver and built-in Airport.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1923477